# How do I make the IsEnabled property of a button dependent on the presence of data in other controls? (WPF)

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, data-binding

I have a "Login" button that I want to be disabled until 3 text boxes on the same WPF form are populated with text (user, password, server).

I have a backing object with a boolean property called IsLoginEnabled which returns True if and only if all 3 controls have data.  However, when should I be checking this property?  Should it be on the LostFocus event of each of the 3 dependent controls?

Thanks!

vg1890

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd get the "backing object" to raise the `IsLoginEnabled` changed event when any of the 3 fields are updated. You can then bind the button to the IsLoginEnabled property and not have to keep checking it.

The pseudocode would look something like this:

```
Public Event IsLoginEnabledChanged As EventHandler

Public Property User() As String
Get..   ' snipped for brevity
Set(ByVal value As String)
   mUser = value
   RaiseEvent IsLoginEnabledChanged(Me, New EventArgs())
End Set

' do the same in the Set for Password() and Server() properties
```

The trick to this is naming the Event `[PropertyName]Changed` (i.e. `IsLogonEnabledChanged`) - because raising this event will automagically notify any bound controls  :o)

Comment: Alternately, your backing object could implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I would say the easiest option would be to check it on the LostFocus or TextChanged event of each of those controls.  However, if you want to do a little heavier lifting, you could implement the boolean as a dependency property that you could have bound to the button's Enable.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750428.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Can you just databind your IsLoginEnabled right to the Enabled property of the login button?

Comment: Only if it is a dependency property, as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use **RoutedCommands** one of the most useful features of WPF. Basically add a **CommandBinding**, to use **OnExecute** and **OnQueryCommandEnabled** to manage button's enabled state.

[Check out this wonderful explanation on using RoutedCommands in WPF](http://blogs.msdn.com/dancre/archive/2006/08/05/dm-v-vm-part-5-commands.aspx)